# Is it safe not to include a home button in the main navigation?

Tags: navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Home button vs Logo link?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/home-button-vs-logo-link)

Is it safe not to include a home button in the main navigation because the logo already links to it?

Answer (score 3):

I think yes. Users are generally used to go to the home page through the logo. It's big and really easy to find, common practice I would say. I actually hate pages with logos that do nothing...

Comment: I don't think the OP was suggesting *removing* the link to the homepage from the logo and keeping a navigation link, it was more about whether the link in the nav is required anymore because the logo link is always present.

Comment: @JonW I know. I didn't say anything about removing a link... I just said that the logo link is enough and home button is not mandatory