# Should we stop using "Home" in navigation?

Tags: navigation, user-behavior, user-research, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Home button vs Logo link?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/home-button-vs-logo-link)

The following must be true for most (if not all) websites:

Clicking the logo or website name leads to the homepage (/index.html).

But the question is, would most people (preferably all) know to click it if there was no "Home" in the nav?

---

One can assume that the navigation would contain the usual suspects: About, Services, Blog, Contact, etc.

How many users would comfortably click the logo/name to get to the homepage?

How many would not know what to do?

How many would know, but hesitate and be frustrated by the website, or develop a negative association?

---

Different websites would have a different demographic of visitors - I wonder how this is for people wealthier in years (40-60 or more).

Is it better to leave "Home" where it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [good discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/home-button-vs-logo-link) on this in another thread and the consensus was that it still bore relevance in usability and that it should stay.

For your particular case, however, it might be instructive to add a ?ref= param to your logo and home button link and look at your analytics to determine what your site visitors are actually doing.

You might be surprised how many people use the home link in the nav.

Comment: Thanks Charles, the only issue with having both and seeing which users use more is that it's not possible to know whether those clicking "Home" would or would not have clicked the logo

Comment: you could AB test this. show half of your uses one version and show the other half the other. mabey just for a week or until you see how people are using your site

Comment: True. Would also be interesting to know if anyone has done this already!

Comment: But another issue is that users now aren't necessarily users that, for example, SEO efforts are trying to bring in for the future. So it'd be best to quantify global web trends...