# Navigation on subdomain site

Tags: usability, navigation

I'm redesigning and simplifying a FAQ page and I've run into a navigation problem.

In the main nav bar, I have to include both the logo of the company, a link to the FAQ index and a link to go back to the main site.

I have doubts concerning where should the logo link to, as the user might expect to go to the FAQ index but as it's the company logo for me it would make sense to also return the user to the main site.

Any comments on what would be the best way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Logos should *ALWAYS* link home. There is no scenario in which a company logo should just link to anything but the main home page of the site. While it may make sense for YOUR site for the logo to link elsewhere, your user has been conditioned to expect logos to link to the home page based on the hundreds if not thousands of other web pages they've been to that use that feature. If you want the logo to link to the FAQ homepage, then redesign the log to include the company log AND have the word FAQ somewhere in that logo so that there is zero confusion as to where that link will take users. If you do that you can have the main site link right above that in small letters, the way the stack exchange and user experience logos are laid out on this page.

2) If the logo is a link to the main site, there should be no reason to have a link to the main site. I'd talk with whoever gave you that design spec and ask the reason for that.

3) You can use breadcrumbs after to show a link to the FAQ home page

Attached below, quick 30 second wireframe/sketch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a link is going to be put on the logo it should always lead back to the home page of the site. It is pretty much universally accepted that the **logo should lead back home** and to do otherwise is to **practice incorrect UX**. You would only complicate a users experience by having the logo lead to a FAQ or anything else.

That being said if you don't have to include a button in the navigation bar that links back to home you can simplify the whole process **simply by having the logo on every page** and can always be used to go home rather **than both a logo with a link and a home page button**.

This may help your decision as well: [Home button vs Logo link?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/home-button-vs-logo-link)