# Accessing Home screen from Logo placed on the Webpage - Why this is a common practice followed in most of the sites?

Tags: user-expectation, web-app

We are working on a designing a web application that has a Dashboard. The discussion is on whether to have the Dashboard as separate item on the Navigation or make it accessible by clicking the company logo on the top bar.

What are your thoughts on deciding how this should be?

Comment: Probably relevant / potentially duplicate: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/home-button-vs-logo-link

Answer (score 3):

As general rule, links should be labeled with the title of the page they navigate to. Often, if you're building a website for, say, a company called MGI®, then the home page (mgi.com) would simply be titled "MGI®", as in "You've arrived at us." The logo is nothing more than the company name with graphic branding, so if the MGI logo is a link, then it should link to the home page in that case.

It's hard to say if this should apply in your case. Is your dashboard equivalent to the whole company? Most often not. The "company" is probably something more general and there probably already is a (public) home page for the company. If so, a logo in your app linking to the dash instead of the company home page constitutes an unnecessary inconsistency.

If your *app* has a logo of its own, *that* could link to the dashboard if the dashboard represents the app as a whole (and users see the app that way).

Plain text is usually safest, so just label the link as "Dashboard." If the dashboard is indeed the dash for the company's overall performance, you could integrate the word "Dashboard" into the logo graphic, so the link is effectively labeled "MGI® Dashboard"