# Do users know that clicking the logo on a website will take them to home page?

Tags: website-design, hyperlinks, user-expectation, consistency

I had a discussion with a colleague about using "Home" link in main (top) navigation. I know that I should give more options to users, so, my question is not about I should use "Home" link or logo link (or both), is more related about users consciousness about this feature.

**Is there any study made about user consciousness related to clicking logo to navigating to home page?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check out a few earlier posts on the topic, this one appears to be the most recent, and it is linked with some older posts that are still relevant:

[Is 'Home' button still a must?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17472/is-home-button-still-a-must)

Slowly but surely, the percentage of people who are aware that the logo navigates to home will continue to rise. But honestly right now I think it comes down to your user base, 100%. This would be a great question for you to tackle with a round of usability studies, especially since you could include it as a quick and easy add-on to a bigger study.

Remember to give some thought to *when* they want to go home, and *why*.

- Are they wanting to see an overview of your website?
- Are they trying
  to get somewhere specific, but the only path they know of is through
  the home page? (In which case, maybe you could provide clearer
  navigation headings).
- Are they genuinely lost and don't know where
  they want to go?

What action did they take directly before, and what are they trying to accomplish by going home? Maybe there's a more intuitive way to get them from point A to point B.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, there is no specific study about that, but there are many studies about consistent behaviour and the user reaction after an inconsistent situation.

So far, most of the sites take you to the home page with the logo, so it's expected. If something different is going to happen when the logo is clicked, is to have no reaction at all. But if the logo takes you to different places on different situations, that would be too unpredictable and would generate frustration, and doubts.

A site that has a "modal logo" would require the user to learn it's behaviour just by memory since there is no way on the area to be clicked to provide easy directions or instructions. Providing information on a tooltip would be cumbersome and not efficient since the user may click on it before reading it. The user won't be able to easily associate action and reaction.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on your target audience.

As a designer/developer for a public library website, I use both.  I don't have a source to back this up, but I think in general the younger demographic will be more aware that the logo takes you to the home page.  For older people, it might be a good idea to keep the familiar "home" link around.