# Do I need an extra home link when I have the logo on the right hand side

Tags: navigation

When I build a website I'd usually put the logo on the top left of the screen (or in the middle if applicable) and at the same time use it as the link to the home page. I think this became a common pattern today. But I'd instinctively would never put it on the top right.

In a new project I have a client who's CI exactly requires this: the logo has to sit top-right without excuses for online media.

Now I'm wondering if I can still use it as a home link.

From a gut feeling I'd say no and would put an extra home link in the main nav. 
I would not expect a user to consider the logo on the right as the home button. As well, the page is not fully fluid, so that the logo might even disappear on smaller screens. (This as well should be an issue for CI but it obviously is not).

However, the navigation is perfect without the link and I'd rather love to focus the other items than having an extra "home".

What are other arguments for the one or the other approach?

Comment: There are several useful questions around this concept - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17472/is-home-button-still-a-must and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/home-button-vs-logo-link. I had thought they're duplicates but you're specifically referring to the logo on the Right hand side, rather than just talking about a clickable logo in general.

Comment: You can use the logo as a home link to provide convenience but you should ALWAYS have an easily identifiable Home/Main link in your navigation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put a Home link.

As you said: 'the page is not fully fluid, so that the logo might even disappear on smaller screens.'

So in this case you should consider adding a home link when the logo is gone, otherwise it is not so important. The users of the site will adapt to the design, and they will find the link in the right side aswell.
IMO leaving the site without a home link is not a standard practice, and it hardens the navigation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The company logo aka Site ID is not [obviously clickable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Make_Me_Think) and requires thought.
It's not a disastrous flaw but it has a poor discoverability, especially for visually impaired users.